# GitLens extension disappeared

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm work on Linux Mint:
[Screenshot of mint version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EJX5.png)
I have latest version of Visual Studio code:
[Screenshot of vs code version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHtjY.png)
After new reload of OS extension GitLens disappeared: [Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9fVQ.png)
I can't see any information in my source code, that provide this extension. Reinstallation this extension or vs code didn't apply any effect. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was related to python virtual enviroment: extension stoped indexing a lot of files of virtual enviroment. Solvation was easy: exclude virtual enviroment from project folder through moving it outside or exclude through settings

Comment: The actual answer is down below

Comment: I marked this as answer because it was solution. Solution down below is related to other problem. The situation in question was independently of any other steps and was not solved with solution down below.

Answer (score 227):

For me the problem was for VS Code 1.51.1 and GitLens 11 they have made the **Source Control Layout** as default and requires the selection of view in order to make it work as before i.e., in the VS Code sidebar (using Mac OS Catalina 10.15.2).

After update:

1. Press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> ***(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> on Windows)*** and type > **Gitlens: Show Welcome View** and hit enter. This will bring back the GitLens on sidebar. Then click on GitLens icon in sidebar and you will be shown a welcome page similar to screenshot below:

[image]

2. Click on **Welcome (Quick Setup)**, this will open the below screen:

[image]

3. Scroll to the bottom and then select the view named **GITLENS LAYOUT** among the two options given:

[image]

4. Now click on **Close** button in GitLens menu that is opened next to VS Code sidebar:

[image]

And your GitLens is back!

Comment: When they upgrade to 11, I missed the Welcome setup and wondering where's the GitLens in the sidebar. Turns out just a layout change.

Comment: Yeah I committed the same mistake and it was not easy to figure this out as normally the developers have a habit to quickly close these welcome pages and get back to work! ;) It took me a while to figure this out though :)

Comment: I was scared for a minute :D thank god there is stackoverflow

Comment: Exactly. So often I wish stuff just kept working as before.

Comment: Cool! For me worked even shorter version - "cmd+shift+p" > "Gitlens: Welcome" > "Gitlens layout" > open your project

Answer (score 9):

Update from [eamodio/vscode-gitlens issue 516](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/issues/516):

> Antivirus deleted one of the extension's files. To fix issue on Windows:
>
> - Remove GitLens extension from VSCode
> - Reload VSCode
> - Close all instances of VSCode
> - Delete `%userprofile%\.vscode\extensions\eamodio.gitlens-8.5.6`
> - Open VSCode
> - Reinstall GitLens extension

For Mac users:

> - remove the extension
> - reload vscode
> - go to `setting.json` by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> > open user settings
> - delete all entries regarding the extension
> - close vs code
> - open vscode
> - install the extension

---

Original answer:

Do a right click in the plugin icons column, and see if GitLens is hidden or not:

[image: GitLens hidden]

By selecting GitLens, you would find back your GitLens icon:

[image: GitLens is back]

The [OP anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8536982/anderson) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575341/gitlens-extension-disappeared/52575990#comment104866792_52575990)

> In issue 516 on Github problem was solved.
>   This problem was in large count of files, that GitLens extension could not read.
>   **Exclude this path from project's directory solved my problem**.

Comment: Thank for your support, but this didn't work [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/AnmuX0Z.png) I have created bug report for this case on official GitHub page.

Comment: @anderson I see: https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/issues/516. Does the issue persists with the latest VSCode 1.28 that just got released yesterday?

Comment: @anderson I have updated the answer with the result of issue 516.

Comment: thank for a long time support. In issue 516 on Github problem was solved. This problem was in large count of files, that GitLens extension could not read. Exclude this path from project's directory solved my problem.

Comment: @anderson OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: GitLens text does not show on that plugins icon columns when i right click it...

Comment: @MonneratRJ Check if the extension GitLens is installed or activated, try and "Reload Window". I do see that menu entry.

Comment: To be honest I had to reinstall it and then i went into the settings to change the interface type to the "gitlens layout" like the answer provided by @patrick.1729... Going thru the welcome page didn't do the trick for me, i had to search within settings...

Comment: it works! thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with this but found a solution. Just right-click on your visual studio's sidebar and click source control to check it.

Comment: This problem was related to python virtual enviroment: extension stoped indexing a lot of files of virtual enviroment. Solvation was easy: exclude virtual enviroment from project folder through moving it outside or exclude through settings

Answer (score 0):

I just selected source control on vscode's sidebar and then clicked on "start repository". This worked for me on windows.

Comment: Hi João Ignácio , welcome to Stackoverflow.

To help other users, can you add more detail to your answer, for instance the versions of GitLens, VSCode and Windows?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).